# Did the Orcs care about their children in LotR?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, hobbits

I was just Wondering if Orcs brought up their children to be just like them?

Is there any information about childcare as practiced by the Orcs?

Comment: There seems to be no mention of female orcs or orc children. I don't think this is answerable.

Comment: In *The Silmarillion* it is stated 'the Orcs had life and multiplied after the manner of the Children of Ilúvatar', i.e. Orcs procreate in the same way as Elves and Men. This obviously suggests Orcs raise children.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28173/where-do-orc-babies-come-from - this is a good round-up of pretty much all the information about Orc children that Tolkien ever provided, and you're honestly not going to get an answer that says anything different to what's already said there.

Comment: Best asked on parenting.stackexchange.com :P

Answer (score 1):

There is no information about child-raising amongst orcs in either books or movies. In the movies, we see that the Urukhai are in some kind of a synthetic bubble (mother?) that looks very much like a mud surrounded soft egg shape, before they are either pulled out or break out to assume their full size and potential. The insinuation from the early tales (see The Silmarillion, etc)is that Morgoth bred orcs from corrupted men or elves. I have thus assumed that there are no children amongst orcs despite the use of the word "bred" in the earlier tales. Perhaps we should ask Christoper Tolkien?